# Single object in mongodb-collection [v 3.0.2]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to have a collection (test) to contain only one element. Therefore I have a update-query set to an empty object:

```
db.test.find() -> empty
var mongoData = {"name": "Biff"};
db.test.update({}, mongoData, {upsert:true}, cb);
db.test.find() -> {"name": "Biff", "_id":"1"}  

var mongoData = {"name": "Buff"}; 
db.test.update({}, mongoData, {upsert:true}, cb);
db.test.find() -> {"name": "Buff", "_id":"1"}
```

Why isn't it this:

```
db.test.find() -> empty
var mongoData = {"name": "Biff"};
db.test.update({}, mongoData, {upsert:true}, cb);
db.test.find() -> {"name": "Biff", "_id":"1"}   

var mongoData = {"name": "Buff"};
db.test.update({}, mongoData, {upsert:true}, cb);
db.test.find() -> [{"name": "Biff", "_id":"1"}, {"name": "Buff", "_id":"2"}]
```

Updating an empty object '{}' seems to ensure that there isn't created another element in this collection. I thought, that {} couldn't be found, so {"name":"Biff"} gets created and a _id is set to it. If I try to update {} another time, it is not creating {"name":"Biff"} again with a different _id.
It is overwriting the only element in the collection. 
Why is this so?

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: mongodb version 3.0.2

Comment: Your "code" driver. Not the database version. Node native? Monk? mongojs?

Comment: nodejs mongodb: "^2.0.28

Comment: So the node native driver then

Comment: Empty conditions {} matches any document in collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call false on this:

Here is the code listing to prove it, if your own code differs then this should be a guide:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var collection = db.collection('bifftest');

  async.eachSeries(
    ["Biff","Buff"],
    function(name,callback) {
      collection.update({},{ "name": name },{ "upsert": true },callback);   
    },
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Returns:

```
[ { _id: 55b8992dcc8638610dca2e7c, name: 'Buff' } ]
```

Just as expected.

Comment: Thanks alot. I need getting used to that an empty object does match all documents of the collection.

Comment: @marcel Yes it **does** match everything in the collection. The other information that told you otherwise is incorrect. My code here should be exactly the same as what you posted. If you are seeing otherwise then the code producing different behavior is not the same as your post or here. Check your actual code in your application for the differences.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem here as MongoDB works like that. The `insert` part of `upsert` occurs only in case if the match criteria does not hit any document:

> upsert: If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria

So in your case, the find criteria (empty document `{}`) matches all the documents in the collection, thus it does not `insert` a new document and instead updates all existing.

Comment: Okies, thanks, to "Blakes Seven" and "stdob" too. I wasn't sure if a empty object could match all documents in the collection

Comment: Still not correct. Look at the code as posted in my response. Nothing wrong with what the OP posted, but something is likely wrong with the code they did not post.

Comment: @BlakesSeven can't get your point :/ I think we talk about the same thing. Am I missing something?